# Git - Get name of modified files of unpushed changes in a unpushed branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a git hook that will do some processing on committed changes that are not pushed yet, and I'm struggling to get the list of modified files in this specific case: I have a local branch that is NOT in remote yet. This branch is NOT based on master (For example, imagine I have a production branch of certain version).

If this the branch was based on master, then it's quite easy as I can do this:

`git diff origin/master..HEAD --name-only`

If the branch is already in remote, then it's quite easy as I can do this:

`git diff origin/<Name of My Branch>..HEAD --name-only`

But, in my case, I cannot assume any of those. What are good ways to do this? I'd like to do something like this, but I could not figure out how to specify the local branch there easily because it is not master, and it's some other branch.

`git diff <Local branch>..HEAD --name-only`

Comment: `git show HEAD --name-only --diff-filter=M` ?

Comment: @Paolo That shows the only last unpushed commit. If there were multiple commits that were not pushed yet, it won't work.

Comment: So how many do you want to show? How can you expect to know how many haven't been pushed since the remote doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you explain the workflow in more detail? The question leaves a lot of room for speculation, but your comment on LeGEC's answer suggests you may know what to compare `HEAD` against. In git, branches are simply "links" to a specific commit, so you can just replace `master` with `production` (with or without `origin/`). In case there are multiple production branches (for each version, for example), but follow a versioned naming scheme - it can be easily scripted.

Comment: @Paolo You can commit as many as you want before you push. I want to show _all_ commits that are not pushed yet.

Comment: @CookieEater so I imagine that means ALL commits for the branch, since a remote branch doesn't exist for that branch right?

Comment: @micromoses Yes, I _could_ come up with a script to get the branch to compare against, but that sounds completely unnecessary to me as git should know what commits are not pushed yet.

Comment: @CookieEater git does not explicitly track/index unpushed commits. I saw your solution, and while git has many internal optimizations, the command still asks git to scan the entire repository, which may be fine for small repos, but possibly become painful as the repo grows. Again, stressing the word "possibly". It might never be an issue for you.

Comment: @micromoses I see. Thanks a lot for the valuable input. If I have any issues, I can perhaps come back to update it here.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to take `master` as a reference by default:

```
# if your current branch has no registered remote:
git diff --name-only origin/master..<commit>
```

In my experience, this is very often more than enough.

---

If you really want to be more precise about what should be pushed, you may try something funkier to determine what is "the closest commit known to your remote repository" and diff against that :

```
# step by step:
# the following command will print the name of all known remote branches:
git branch -r --format="%(refname:short)"

# the following command will print a list of shas for commits in your branch
# and not yet on the remote:
git rev-list HEAD --not $(git branch -r --format="%(refname:short)")

# get the last of these commits:
last=$(git rev-list HEAD --not $(git branch -r --format="%(refname:short)") | tail -1)

# and take its parent:
git diff --name-only ${last}^..HEAD
```

*[update]*

You are right, as you mentioned in your answer, there are shortcuts in git log/git rev-list to list remotes more directly:

```
last=$(git rev-list HEAD --not --remotes | tail -1)
git diff --name-only ${last}^..HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks, `git diff --name-only origin/master..<commit>` won't work in my case. Imagine a production branch that has been forked from master where bugs are backported from master occasionally. It's maintained separately from master. I thought about something similar to what you wrote, and I could perhaps try that.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like this at the end. (Note: This is in PowerShell.)

```
# Use git log to find out the list of commits that are not in remote yet. Then, pick the oldest commit.
$oldestCommitId = git log --branches --not --remotes --format=format:%H | Select-Object -Last 1

# Do a diff from one before that commit (using ^) until the current HEAD.
$files = git diff "$oldestCommitId^..HEAD" --diff-filter=d --name-only
```

Comment: From the question as described, it is only required to check the current branch/head. If so, I suggest removing the `--branches` argument for optimization; from the man page: `Shows all commits that are in any of local branches ...`, which would not be necessary. Additionally, while I'm not sure what `Select-Object` does (I'm not versed in PS), I have a feeling that it may return an undesired result in case more than one local branch has unpushed commits.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually, in my case, it did not work if I don't put `--branches`. As far as I know, Select-Object is a PowerShell equivalent of "Give me the last item in an array". But, you are right that, I probably need to filter out other branches.

Comment: I apologize, what I meant was that explicitly stating a single ref would be better than using the flag, and then the flag can be removed; simply put - replacing `--branches` with `HEAD` should do the trick.